# What is the 'identity function' in AES?

Tags: aes, pbkdf-2

I'm trying to understand how AES works. I got as far as knowing how a password is converted to an unifinished key with the PBKDF2 function. After that [RFC3962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3962#section-4) says that an AES useable key most be derived from the unfinished key:

[image]

Then it refers to the DK function in [RFC3961](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3961#section-5.1), and no further information is left on the DK function in RFC3692. So in RFC3691 it says that:

[image]
[image]

So I went to look for how the random-to-key function is defined. I couldn't find anything, only a small table in [RFC3692](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3962#section-6) that said the random-to-key function is the 'identity function'. I could find no clue on what this identity function was in the RFC3692 document.

Comment: From RFC3692: "To generate an encryption key from a pass phrase and salt string, we
   use the PBKDF2 function from PKCS #5 v2.0 [...] (In [KCRYPTO] terms, the PBKDF2 function
   produces a "random octet string", hence the application of the
   random-to-key function even though it's effectively a simple identity
   operation.) "

Comment: Yes I saw that too ofcourse but I couldn't understand how the final key is derived from the outcome of PBKDF2

Comment: Basically, an identity function simply returns the same value that receives. In this case, since the PBKDF2 function produces a random octet string, which coincidentally, can be used directly as a key, it is not necessary to define an intermediate transformation. In other words, the identity function is enough transformation (as it does nothing)

Comment: So does that mean I can erase the random-to-key part from the definition of the DK function?

Comment: Only in the context of RFC3692. In RFC3691 there are several cases where the random-to-key function is different.